# Custom sorting algorithm in Salesforce Apex

Tags: algorithm, sorting, salesforce-apex

I had a scenario where I needed to sort a list of `EmailTemplate`, but didn't have anything to sort the list by (other than a common number in the `Name` property).

The email templates looked something like this:

```
Some email template - 1
Some other email template - 2
Another email template - 3 (with end text)
Xylophone email template - 4
Aardvark email template - 5 (with end text)
```

Here's the code I wrote:

```
public static List<EmailTemplate> OrderEmailTemplates(List<EmailTemplate> emailTemplates)
{
    Integer n = emailTemplates.size();
    for(Integer i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(Integer j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++)
        {
            if(!AreTemplatesInOrder(emailTemplates[j], emailTemplates[j+1]))
            {
                EmailTemplate temp = emailTemplates[j];
                emailTemplates[j] = emailTemplates[j+1];
                emailTemplates[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    return emailTemplates;
}

private static Boolean AreTemplatesInOrder(EmailTemplate t1, EmailTemplate t2)
{
    return RetrieveNumberFromTemplateName(t1) < RetrieveNumberFromTemplateName(t2);
}

private static Integer RetrieveNumberFromTemplateName(EmailTemplate template)
{
    return Integer.valueOf(template.Name.split('-')[1].replaceAll('[a-zA-Z]{1,}|\\-', '').trim());
}
```

It feels a little verbose considering the task. Perhaps I'm too used to using mordern manipulation/querying technologies like LINQ.

Is there a less verbose way of doing this in Apex?

Some useful syntax would be something like the following, though I'm sure it doesn't exist (ignoring the lambda, it's there for readability):

`emailTemplates.OrderBy((x,y) => AreTemplatesInOrder(x,y));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a less verbose way to achieve this in Apex you need to create a wrapper class for EmailTemplate that implements [Comparable interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_comparable.htm). The advantage is that elements don't need to be manually moved in the array.

```
    public static EmailTemplate[] orderEmailTemplates(List<EmailTemplate> emailTemplates) {
        EmailTemplateWrapper[] wrappers = new List<EmailTemplateWrapper>();
        for(EmailTemplate template : emailTemplates) {
            wrappers.add(new EmailTemplateWrapper(template));
        }
        wrappers.sort();

        EmailTemplate[] sortedTemplates = new List<EmailTemplate>();
        for(EmailTemplateWrapper wrapper : wrappers) {
            sortedTemplates.add(wrapper.record);
        }

        return sortedTemplates;
    }
    
    class EmailTemplateWrapper implements Comparable {
        public EmailTemplate record { public get; set; }
        
        public EmailTemplateWrapper(EmailTemplate record) {
            this.record = record;
        }

        public Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
            if(!(compareTo instanceOf EmailTemplateWrapper)) {
                return -1;
            }
            EmailTemplate otherRecord =  ((EmailTemplateWrapper) compareTo).record;
            Integer numerForThisRecord = retrieveNumberFromTemplateName(record);
            Integer numerForOtherRecord = retrieveNumberFromTemplateName(otherRecord);
            if(numerForThisRecord == numerForOtherRecord ) {
                return 0;
            } else if(numerForThisRecord < numerForOtherRecord) {
                return -1;
            }
            return 1;
        }

        Integer retrieveNumberFromTemplateName(EmailTemplate template){
           return Integer.valueOf(template.Name.split('-')[1].replaceAll('[a-zA-Z]{1,}|\\-', '').trim());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to code Review! by "_to do so_" - is that in response to the OP's question "_Is there a less verbose way of doing this in Apex?_"?

Comment: Hi! Yes. I believe this answer presents less verbose way of sorting array because you don't have to manually move elements in array.